# Criando inputs dinâmicos com value crescente

Tags: javascript, value, campos

Eu tenho um script que já adiciona e retira os campos desejados.
Clico em + ele adiciona e clico no ícone lixeira ele retira..

Até ai esta ok, eu copio a div e ele cria uma nova linha com os elementos

Porém, surgiu a necessidade de colocar no campo inicial um value automático crescente.

```
01
02
03
```

Assim se eu retirar uma linha o número deve ser retirado tbm.

[![Minha necessidade é sempre no campo Tech. ir adicionando com o número sequencial.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        //group add limit
        var maxGroup = 10;

        //add more fields group
        $(".addMore").click(function(){
            if($('body').find('.fieldGroup').length <= maxGroup){
                var fieldHTML = '<div class="form-group fieldGroup">'+$(".fieldGroupCopy").html()+'</div>';
                $('body').find('.fieldGroup:last').after(fieldHTML);
            }else{
                alert('Maximum '+maxGroup+' groups are allowed.');
            }
        });

        //remove fields group
        $("body").on("click",".remove",function(){
            $(this).parents(".fieldGroup").remove();
        });
    });
```

```html
<html lang="pt_br">
 
 <head>
 <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.2/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.2/summernote.js"></script>
    <script src="http://lqez.github.io/summernote-ext-print/summernote-ext-print.js"></script>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    
    <script src="http://digitalbush.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
    
    
 </head>
 
 
 <body>
 
 
 <div class="form-group fieldGroup">
    <div class="col-md-1 " style="">
      <input id="tech[]" name="tech[]" class="form-control" placeholder=""  value="1" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2" style="">
     <input id="registro[]" name="registro[]" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" style="">
      <input id="funcionario[]" name="funcionario[]" class="form-control" placeholder=""value="" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2" style="">
      <input id="funcao[]" name="funcao[]" class="form-control" placeholder=""  value="" type="text"  >
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" style="">
     <input id="assinatura[]" name="assinatura[]" class="form-control" placeholder=""  value="" type="text"  >
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1" style="">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="  addMore">
         <button class="btn btn-primary " type="button" style="  ">
            <i class="fas fa-plus" style="padding: 4px;"></i>
         </button>
     </a>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
                                        
 
 
 <!-- copy of input fields group -->
 
 <div class="form-group fieldGroupCopy" style="display: none;">
   <div class="col-md-1 " style="">
    <input id="tech[]" name="tech[]" class="form-control" placeholder=""  value="aqui o nº sequencial" type="text">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-2" style="">
    <input id="registro[]" name="registro[]" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="" type="text">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3" style="">
    <input id="funcionario[]" name="funcionario[]" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="" type="text"  >
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-2" style="">
    <input id="funcao[]" name="funcao[]" class="form-control" placeholder=""  value="" type="text"  >
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3" style="">
    <input id="assinatura[]" name="assinatura[]" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="" type="text" >
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-1">
     <div class=" center" style=" padding: 0px;">
       <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger remove" style="padding: 0px;  ;">
          <button class="btn btn-danger " type="button" style="  ">
            <i class="fas fa-trash-alt center " style="padding: 2px;"></i>
          </button>
       </a>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pense na seguinte situação: Você adicionou mais 2 grupos, ficando assim a sequência: 1,2 e 3. Alguém remove o grupo de inputs que contém a sequência 2, assim ficaria: 1,3. Como deveria ser o comportamento nesse caso? E se o usuário adicionar um novo grupo? Ficaria 1,3 e 4?

Comment: Acho que você terá problemas, pois você está repetindo **id´s**.

Answer (score 1):

É só criar uma função para enumerar os campos e chamá-la cada vez que um grupo de elementos for criado ou removido:

```
function enumera(){

   $(".fieldGroup [name='tech[]']").each(function(i){
      $(this).val(i+1);
   });

}
```

O argumento `i` da função é o índice dos campos com o `name="tech[]"` encontrados dentro da classe `.fieldGroup`. Como o índice começa com `0`, soma `+1` para iniciar do `1`.

**Veja:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     //group add limit
     var maxGroup = 10;

     //add more fields group
     $(".addMore").click(function(){
         if($('body').find('.fieldGroup').length <= maxGroup){
             var fieldHTML = '<div class="form-group fieldGroup">'+$(".fieldGroupCopy").html()+'</div>';
             $('body').find('.fieldGroup:last').after(fieldHTML);
             enumera();
         }else{
             alert('Maximum '+maxGroup+' groups are allowed.');
         }
     });

     //remove fields group
     $("body").on("click",".remove",function(){
         $(this).parents(".fieldGroup").remove();
         enumera();
     });
     
     
   function enumera(){
   
      $(".fieldGroup [name='tech[]']").each(function(i){
         $(this).val(i+1);
      });
        
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="form-group fieldGroup">
    <div class="col-md-1 " style="">
      <input id="tech[]" name="tech[]" class="form-control" placeholder=""  value="1" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2" style="">
     <input id="registro[]" name="registro[]" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" style="">
      <input id="funcionario[]" name="funcionario[]" class="form-control" placeholder=""value="" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2" style="">
      <input id="funcao[]" name="funcao[]" class="form-control" placeholder=""  value="" type="text"  >
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" style="">
     <input id="assinatura[]" name="assinatura[]" class="form-control" placeholder=""  value="" type="text"  >
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1" style="">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="  addMore">
         <button class="btn btn-primary " type="button" style="  ">
            <i class="fas fa-plus" style="padding: 4px;"></i>
         </button>
     </a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group fieldGroupCopy" style="display: none;">
   <div class="col-md-1 " style="">
    <input id="tech[]" name="tech[]" class="form-control" placeholder=""  value="aqui o nº sequencial" type="text">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-2" style="">
    <input id="registro[]" name="registro[]" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="" type="text">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3" style="">
    <input id="funcionario[]" name="funcionario[]" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="" type="text"  >
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-2" style="">
    <input id="funcao[]" name="funcao[]" class="form-control" placeholder=""  value="" type="text"  >
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3" style="">
    <input id="assinatura[]" name="assinatura[]" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="" type="text" >
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-1">
     <div class=" center" style=" padding: 0px;">
       <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger remove" style="padding: 0px;  ;">
          <button class="btn btn-danger " type="button" style="  ">
            <i class="fas fa-trash-alt center " style="padding: 2px;"></i>
          </button>
       </a>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

> ⚠️ **Repetição de id's**: um problema é que ao criar novos elementos, haverá repetição de id's, o que é errado no padrão HTML. Provavelmente
>   esses id's são desnecessários e deveriam ser removidos.